# null value while using DLookup , i dont find anything mistake ..kindly assist

Tags: ms-access

sid is service ID, Table : Service_MasterData, prefixtext value is a mobile number value , rdate is a date value taking from Dmax , not sure why sid value shows null where in table record is exist.  request someone to assist here ..

```
Dim sid As String     
sid = DLookup("Service_ID", "Service_MasterData", "[Mobile Number]= '" & prefixtext & "' AND [Date Of Service]= " & rdate & "")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using domain aggregate functions, such as DLookup, with dates, you need to "wrap" the date in #. You also need to take care that the date is unambiguous, as 03/04 could read as either 3 April, or 4 March. Try this:

```
sid = DLookup("Service_ID", "Service_MasterData", "[Mobile Number]= '" & prefixtext & "' AND [Date Of Service]= " & Format(rdate,"\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"))
```

Regards

Comment: one of colleague as assisted above that worked even i tried your cod seems to be working  fine but giving compiling error ... Thank for your supporting hand .

Comment: Oops - I missed out a quotation mark in the original answer - now amended.

Comment: Great it works & i am really confuse .. while using my query for this request i used the code which is assisted by June7 but when i was running another query that code dint help me and your code worked successfully .. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use # character to delimit parameters for date/time type field.

`sid = DLookup("Service_ID", "Service_MasterData", "[Mobile Number]= '" & prefixtext & "' AND [Date Of Service]= #" & rdate & "#")`

Comment: Thank you so much for the support it worked as expected